# Correcting marker shadow

Tags: android, shadow, android-maps

I am developing an Android map application.

I've placed markers on the map but shadows are in the wrong position. How can I adjust shadow position?

[image: Incorrect Marker Shadow]

I don't want to remove the shadow. I want to adjust its position behind the marker.

Comment: do you want to remove shadow?

Comment: @SanketKachhela no i think he'd like it to be placed right beneath the marker

Comment: No I don't. I want to adjust shadow position. The bottom point of the shadow and the bottom point of the marker should be at the same point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue in setting the drawable bounds. Your drawable have the bounds set to center, instead of center-bottom.

Ensure that your constructor for `ItemizedOverlay` calls:

```
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
```

and that you set the bounds of any non default drawable you use in `OverlayItem` objects like that:

```
    drawable_gps_pin = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_gps);
    drawable_gps_pin.setBounds((int)(-drawable_gps_pin.getIntrinsicWidth()/2),-drawable_gps_pin.getIntrinsicHeight(), (int)(drawable_gps_pin.getIntrinsicWidth()/2), 0); 
    overlayItem.setMarker(drawable_gps_pin);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove shadow than use below in your itemizedOverlay class

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
    }
```